# Connection to device over SSH unable to connect to WiFI

Tags: wireless

I am relatively new to Linux, and so I may not have the proper knowledge, as I mostly follow the instructions I can find.

I have a BeagleBone Blue (BBBlue) device that I've flashed several times. The first and second times, I was using Debian 9.10. Back then, I was able to connect to the BBBlue's built-in WiFi, use connmanctl to connect it to my private home wifi network, and it would turn on a green LED to show it was connected.

Then after rebooting and reconnecting over WiFi and SSH, both the BBBlue and my laptop would have a connection to the internet.
Now, after installing Ubuntu 16.04 and doing all the steps to connect the BBBlue to WiFi, the laptop has no internet.

The BBBlue has its green LED flashing, and I can SSH to it, and it pings external websites, but the computer itself does not connect to sites.

Comment: I'm guessing nobody knows ‍♀️ but I will update this if I find an answer.